# PHP sort array function

Tags: php

I have a table that consists of comments. Some of them are replies to other comments and have a value set in parent_commentid table. I'm trying to create a function that checks each element in a result set if there is a value in the parent_columnid and if so take the entire element and sort it inside the element with a comment_id that matches the parent_commentid of the current element in the iteration. This is what I've come up with so far.

```
    function sort_comments($comments){
    $result = array();
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        if(is_null($comment['parent_commentid'])) $result[] = $comment;
        else{
            $parent_comment = array_search($comment['parent_commentid'], $comments);
            if($parent_array !== false) $result[$parent_comment][] = $comment;
        }
    }
}
```

array_search is not the function I'm looking for but is the closets thing I could think of. Im not sure where to go from here. Keep in mind also that there can exist replies to other replies.

Comment: I am confused about what you mean by 'elements'. You are talking about comments, then what are the elements?

Comment: Btw. in the 7th line is a "!==" `operator`, which should be "!=".

Comment: I'm also confused. Why doesn't array_search work? How are the comment ID's stored, are they comma separated?

Comment: First, create your hierarchical array where comments are sub-arrays of their parents, as you started to do. Then you will need to write a recursive function. This function takes an array as a parameter. For each item in the array, if that element is also an array (has child comments), call the same function on that item to sort the subarray. Then, sort the current array by whatever column you want to order the comments by. The result will be a sorted hierarchical array.

Comment: Could you provide me with a simple example? A recursive function is when a function calls itself right? yeah would be really helpful with a simple demonstration that applies to what Im trying to do.

Comment: Why is there no [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the comments by their own id, so that you can reference them later:

```
function sort_comments($comments){
    $result = array();
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        if(is_null($comment['parent_commentid'])){ 
            $result[$comment['commentid']] = $comment;
        }else{
            $parent_comment = $result[$comment['parent_commentid']]
            if($parent_comment) 
                $parent_comment[$comment['commentid']] = $comment;
            else
                // what happens in this case:
                // parent_commentid set, but no such comment exists?
        }
    }
```

Note the `$comment['commentid']`. I don't know how you call the id of a comment (`commentid` ?), but since you have a column `parent_commandid` you most likely do have such a column to reference your comments. Use that to store the comments, on top level or inside other comments.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle creating or sorting a representation of the discussion with infinite nesting, it only duplicates the values of the parent_commentid column into another flat array. Just because that's the path he started down doesn't mean continuing his code will lead to the desired result :/

Answer (score 0):

To sort by internal fields of an array I usually use usort. Usort works as a recursive method so you can ensure that everytime you try to sort an element inside an array you will call your custom function. In this way you will get a more clean code.

Here is an example:

```
function cmp_rand_score($a, $b)
{
  if($a["rand_score"] == $b["rand_score"]){
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a["rand_score"] < $b["rand_score"]) ? 1 : -1;
}

//If you are inside a class:
usort($rows, array($this, "cmp_rand_score"));

//If not you can call directly:
usort($rows, "cmp_rand_score");
```

Hope it helps.